# multiple return in rendering a list in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to refactor below code to make it more clean? Especially the multiple return in `renderTodos` method. I also have a confusion, am I creating the `renderTodos` method correctly? Should I place it in the render function? or doing `this.renderTodos()` is ok?

```
export default class TodoList extends Component {

    renderTodos = () => {
        const { todos } = this.props

        return todos.map(todo => {
            return (
                <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} />
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.renderTodos()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want to return the element without any condition or calculation, so you can avoid `{}` and `return` with map.

Like this:

```
renderTodos = () => {
    const { todos } = this.props;

    return todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} /> )
}
```

With this way return inside `renderTodos` is required to return the result from that method.

Another way is put the map part directly inside render method, like this:

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>
            {
                this.props.todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} /> )
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Or better to write it as [Stateless Functional Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components):

```
const TodoList = (props) => (
    <div>
        {
            props.todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} /> )
        }
    </div>
)
```

Check this article: [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Comment: how to know when to use stateless component? i found sometime statless doesn't make sense as I need the lfie cycle method. like for example in todoList component, you need to do infinite scroll, you need life cycle method for the users' scroll event.

Comment: if any component doesn't have to maintain it's own state, no lifecycle methods are required then in that situation it's better to use stateless functional component, stateless fun. com. mainly responsible for ui, how things will looks, doesn't have much functionality part, check this nice article on this: [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using `renderTodos` as a callback to be passed as a `prop`, you can render it directly in the final `render()`.

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>
            {props.todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm also using implicit return here.

Also, since your component doesn't maintain any `state`, and just accepts `props` and renders JSX, you can turn it into a stateless functional component -

```
const TodoList = props => {
      return(
          <div>
              {props.todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} />}
          </div>
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a stateless component so you can just use a plain function instead of a class. Additionally, you don't actually have a multiple return in renderTodos since one of the return statements is actually another function entirely (though you can make it a one liner pretty easily removing the necessity for the return statement).

Note that the spaceship operator "=>" signifies that the parameter of .map is an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
function Todo(props) {
    return props.todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} />);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have state, you can make your entire component [functional](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components).

```
function TodoList(props) {
  return <div>{props.todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} />)</div>;
}
```

Comment: how to know when to use stateless component? i found sometime stateless doesn't make sense as I need the lfie cycle method. like for example in todoList component, you need to do infinite scroll, you need life cycle method for the users' scroll event.